# Deserialize to Optional<List<MyPojo>> explodes with HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, option-type

I am using `jackson-datatype-jdk8` library to deserialize from json to `Optional` fields in my POJO, configured via:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

I am using Optional because I need to able to distinguish between the field being present in the json but with a value of `null`, which deserializes as `Optional.empty()`, and not having the field at all, which deserializes as `null` (in order to implement PATCH rest method).

This works perfectly for simple types, but not for `Optional` of `Lists`, eg:

```
class MyPojo {
    String plainString;                     // Works
    Optional<String> optionalString;        // Works
    List<String> plainStrings;              // Works
    Optional<List<String>> optionalStrings; // Explodes if json contains data, eg "optionalStrings" : ["foo"]
}
```

The exact error is:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Class java.lang.String not subtype of [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class com.foo.MyPojo]];
>   nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class java.lang.String not subtype of [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class com.foo.MyPojo]]`

The context is spring boot, which uses ObjectMapper.
All jackson libraries at latest version, which is currently `2.10.3`.
Sample unremarkable json that should work:

```
{
  "plainString": "foo",
  "optionalString": "foo",
  "plainStrings": [
    "foo"
  ],
  "optionalStrings": [
    "foo"
  ]
}
```

To be clear, deserializing to `Optional<String> optionalString` works as expected, ie:

- missing from payload -> `null`
- in payload with null value -> `Optional.empty()`
- in payload with a value -> `Optional.of(value)`

But when the field is an Optional List type, deserialization explodes.

Is there a work around?
Do I need to an annotation or configuration?

Comment: Can you show (1) the JSON causing this problem and (2) how you're connecting that `objectMapper` to your MVC converter infrastructure? (Spring autoregisters that module if present on the classpath, by the way.) Are you using Boot?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- the json is obvious and unmysterious. objectmapper is a bean that has extra configuration that is not relevant. As per question, using spring boot. As I said, it's all working perfectly, except for `Optional<Collection>` types, which explode.

Comment: I missed the Boot part of the post. Nevertheless, "unmysterious" or not, this isn't an MCVE without the input, and it would be relevant for attempting to debug whether you're getting this on absent, null, or what-contents.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- I don't see how it adds value, but here you go: `{"plainString":"foo","optionalString":"foo","plainStrings":["foo"],"optionalStrings":["foo"]}`, where the field `optionalString` is assigned `Optional.of("foo")`

Comment: I would assume, the question doesn't treat *"`Optional` as a poor choice being an attribute and worse further wrapping a `Collection` within"*, hence getting rid of it as a better way to fix it. @Bohemian Isn't it?

Comment: @naman optional is necessary to distinguish between the payload not containing a field, and the payload containing the field with a value of null. Without optional, both would set the field to null. I would like to hear any ideas you may have of how to implement this functionality without it, noting of course that the json is inaccessible to the application.

Comment: @Bohemian practically (not with spring boot), I have mostly gotten away with three possible states, 1. the payload not containing the field, 2. payload containing the field with value null and 3. an actual list value in the payload. The first two are eventually empty list for me and the actual payload the other side of it. What makes you create another state and for what significance? (This goes towards a design choice and might not be worth discussing here. As said, we could possibly assume that `Optional<List<String>>` is more of a requirement and not a choice for the scope of the question.)

Comment: @Naman the four fields are totally unrelated to each other. They are provided as examples of what works and doesn't work. Specifically, proving the deserialising simple objects to Optional works as expected, ie missing -> null, null value -> Optional.empty() and value -> Optional.of(value)

Comment: @Bohemian Works fine for me. Worth updating your question with some spring-boot configuration related to object mapper.

Comment: @smile that is good news. I’ll start stripping away config and see if I can recover correct functionality

Comment: And the error you have shared seems to suggest you are not using the same json which is present in the question. Worth rechecking.